# OAuth1 and Moving from SHA-1 to SHA-256

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, administration

Today our Java middle-ware communicates with our SalesForce.com app via OAuth version 1.

Will it still work after the upgrade to SHA-256? 
Should I upgrade to OAuth 2?

Appreciate any help.

### Update

I tried to test OAuth 1 against a send-box org which was already upgraded to SHA 256 and got this HTTPS error

> "LOGIN_OAUTH_MUST_USE_HTTPS_WITH_AUTH_HEADER"

I assume OAuth 2 will solve this

### Update - 2

Apparently OAuth 1 is working well with the new migration to SHA-256.
I consulted with a few of SalesForce.com R&D and Product executives and I also verified it by testing it against a Sandbox org (all Sandbox orgs had already been migrated to SHA 256).

I do wonder if SalesForce.com will still support OAuth 1 in the future...